# Ultra math search engine

Tags: mathematical-software, online-resources

Does anyone know searching engine for arxiv.org math formulas?
Like https://www.searchonmath.com and https://approach0.xyz/search/
In my opinion, we should have a search engine that can find formulas for all the journals and eventually all internet to make research progress more efficient.

Comment: A related question on this site: [Which tools can identify scholarly papers that use the same types of equations?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/162487) (And here are two question about searching on the Internet rather than in mathematical articles - on [math.se]: [How to search the internet for strings that consist mostly of math notation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/74609) On [math.meta.se]: [What is the best way to search for a math equation on the internet?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12993))

Comment: I think it's helpful and do you know how they made it? Because I'm thinking about creating a new search engine using AI like GPT-3(https://openai.com/blog/openai-api/).

Comment: @Georg Kang: The author of Approach0 is often present [in this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/46148/in-the-search-of-a-question). Also he mentioned [being pretty busy right now](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/46148/2021/9/2). In any case, the source code is available on GitHub and I think that he also published some papers related to this project.