# Search publications for LaTeX code

Tags: soft-question, gm.general-mathematics, software, research-tools

Is there a way to search the literature for specific instances of formulas (and variants), perhaps using $\rm\LaTeX$ code?

Comment: Here is a related question: [Which tools can identify scholarly papers that use the same types of equations?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/162487)

Comment: https://www.searchonmath.com or https://approach0.xyz/search/ are two options (but they have not indexed the entire web)

Comment: Approach has Math SE and “Art of Problem Solving” indexed ([source](https://approach0.xyz/guide/content/en/index.html#what-the-search-engine-actually-looks-for)). – SearchOnMath has many more sites indexed, but is not free ([source](https://www.searchonmath.com/terms-of-use)).